# How to read a set of characters from a file and interpret it

Tags: java

```
  switch (secondLine) {
                    case "EEEEEEEEEEEE":
                        System.out.println("12 mistakes");
                        break;
                    case "............":
                        System.out.println("All test passed");
                        break;
                    //If a student fails 1-11 then check the file for the thirdLastLine and return the integer
                    default:

                        System.out.println("You failed some test and here is your result: " + secondLine);

                        break;
```

I want to be able to indicate the E's and failure and the exact position within the set of characters. the compiler would return something like E..E....E..E

Thank you

Comment: Where would this data be coming from, and in what format?

Comment: There is a total of 12 in the format. The data comes from the second line of a text file in this format 'EEEEEEEEEEEE' for all failures depending on the number equivalent and '............' if the student passes everything but when there is a failure then the output contains something like 'E..E...E...E'

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the String in order to find the indexes of Es and also calculate the amount.

```
int failures = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < secondLine.length(); i++)
{
    char c = secondLine.charAt(i);
    if (c == 'E') { failures++; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, you can do it like `int failures = secondLine.length() - secondLine.replace("E", "").length()`

Comment: True, but that is a very inefficient and wasteful solution.

Comment: Hi Clashsoft, I have keep getting a list in my output which isnt right but it does say how many test was failed but not in the right order. for exams I ran the code on a result with output in the second line like '...E.....E...E.' but the code returned in a list 1,2,3 instead of saying one failure found in 3,10 and 14. please help

Comment: Could you give me your code? I am guessing you are adding the amount to the list instead of the index.

Comment: I get something like 'Failures 4' as the output but I really want something like you have Failed Test 1, 4, 8 and 11 by reading the index? Thanks :) between I couldnt post my switch statement as the character limit deprived me

Comment: Hi I have just figured out a way of solving the problem using indexOf() in my for loop. Thanks for the help :) I really appreciate